# Calculating number of clients accessing database at the same time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making an online examination system which is a window application.  I'm using SQL server and C#. There are multiple clients and one server. How can I calculate the number of clients that can access the server at the same time by installing client and server on same PC? what the parameters required to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [sp_who](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

`select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_sessions` is your friend!

If you want to know a list of users, along with the SQL statement they last executed you could use a statement like:

```
    SELECT nt_domain + '\' + nt_user_name AS User, host_name, program_name, t.text
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r ON s.session_id = r.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t
    ORDER BY nt_domain + '\' + nt_user_name AS User, host_name, program_name
```